# error MSB4062 while trying to compile vs-android application

Tags: android, visual-studio, vs-android

I am using [vs-android](http://code.google.com/p/vs-android/) to compile the sample application available on their site. I am using the Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview

> error MSB4062: The "GCCCompile" task could not be loaded from the assembly 
>   C:\ProgramFiles (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Platforms\Android\vs-android.Build.CppTasks.Android.dll. 
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.Common, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 
>   Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, 
>   and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

I have slightly modified the file

> Microsoft.Cpp.Android.Targets

to look for dll file mentioned in the error.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Platforms\Android\ImportBefore\*.targets" Condition="Exists('$(VCTargetsPath)\Platforms\Android\ImportBefore')" />
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets" />

  <UsingTask TaskName="GCCCompile" AssemblyFile="$(VCTargetsPath)Platforms\Android\vs-android.Build.CppTasks.Android.dll" />
  <UsingTask TaskName="GCCLink" AssemblyFile="$(VCTargetsPath)Platforms\Android\vs-android.Build.CppTasks.Android.dll" />
  <UsingTask TaskName="GCCLib" AssemblyFile="$(VCTargetsPath)Platforms\Android\vs-android.Build.CppTasks.Android.dll" />
  <UsingTask TaskName="AntBuild" AssemblyFile="$(VCTargetsPath)Platforms\Android\vs-android.Build.CppTasks.Android.dll" />
  <UsingTask TaskName="VCMessage" AssemblyName="Microsoft.Build.CppTasks.Common, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

VCTargetsPath is correct, I have checked. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not work with Visual Studio 11. Only vs2010 for now.